# In C#, how do I solve multiple enumeration warning when one use is in base constructor call?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, radix

The following code gives me a warning about possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable:

```
public ClassName(IEnumerable<OtherClassName> models) : base(models)
{
    _models.AddRange(models);
}
```

The normal solutions for removing this warning do not work because of the "base" call. I cannot convert to a list because there is no place to store that list.

Is my only option to make the constructor take a list as a parameter? Is that recommended practice in this case?

Comment: base class will already store `models`. Why do you need `_models.AddRange(models);` ?

Comment: a) I need/want to store locally because although parent class does store, it stores as base class and I want to avoid downcasting when I use it locally. 
b) It is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create another private constructor which takes `List<OtherClassName>` and call it using `this` keyword:

```
public ClassName(IEnumerable<OtherClassName> models)
    : this(models.ToList())
{
}

private ClassName(List<OtherClassName> models)
    : base(models)
{
    _models.AddRange(models);
}
```

And make sure you really need to store `models` within your class. Maybe it's already stored in `base` class and you can use it from there?

Comment: Simple and great answer

Comment: Actually, this answer has turned out to be a problem. It is creating an extra copy of the enumeration. When the list got very large, that extra list is a bit of an issue. Having two copies (one in parent and one in child), fine, but three copies -- that temporary created just to call the base class -- that's a problem. I'm not sure how we're going to refactor to handle it, but I wanted to record here that although this is a good solution for the general problem, it does have a downside.